# Why is my /clone command not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I built a spaceship and now I want it to fly into the air one block at a time using command blocks. [image: command blcok]

When I go to run the clock inside, it says Succesfully cloned 45 blocks, like you can see in the bottom left, but the ship doesnt actually move at all. It just says it cloned and stays there. As well as that, it destroys the top row, but just on the command block's column. Any help with either of these problems? Thanks

Comment: Which way were you facing in your image? North, south, east, or west?

Comment: South, positive Z. @ExpertCoder14